# Does Imperatrix Umbrosa Act II have any effect on the Raiden Shogun playable character?

Tags: genshin-impact

> Completing the Inazuma Archeon quest permanently changes some details for the  playable version of the "Raiden Shogun" character. The duality between the puppet and Ei is made more clear by adding more voice lines and [the Serenitea Pot version of the character is switched to Ei](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FG5klFIByaY).

Based on this, does completing the second part of the Raiden Shogun Archeon quest cause any change to the playable version of the character?

Answer (score 1):

I have just checked in game, and yes, there is something related to that quest within her voice lines, in the "Interesting things" tab iirc

> It's about how Makoto turned into the Sacred Sakura Tree

Edit: it seems this voice line was already there, so it implies that there is nothing noticeable of change into the Raiden Shogun playable character after finishing the Imperatrix Umbrosa Act II.
There may be something in her dialogues in the Serenitea Pot, but with the maintenance still on during the time of writing this answer, I personally have no way of verifying

Edit 2: There is a change related to exploration however:

> Ei abolished the Sakoku decree, which means now we can take the Waverider out of Inazuman seas, and maybe, the Kaeya bridge is now able to go all the way to Inazuma

Comment: There is a problem with that. That specific line existed since the first release of the character (it is not something added in a following update like some of the "About: character" related lines that get added when a new character is released) and does not require the player to complete the second part of the story quest. For those reason that specific line was actually something that made very little sense back then, to the point that it was at the center of many theories... see for example [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Genshin_Impact/comments/po8g2f).

Comment: Basically, it is not something that the quest unlocks or change but instead a sort of "red herring" to the quest content.

Comment: Oh, then, my answer is incorrect, sorry for that

Comment: Well, it is still related to the quest, but I am specifically locking for changes that are unlocked only after the quest is completed. Not going to downvote, but I can't accept this as an answer either.

Comment: there is one big change that is not tied to the character, you can use the waverider to sail all around the available map of Teyvat after you finish that quest. I do not know if that is a change you are looking for

Comment: [see here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61098897#61098897)